# Fail loading DLL

Tags: c++, dll

DLL loading fail, In other branch without casting to strFile, directly they are loading `LoadLibrary(strFile);`, and in project properties character set is setted to multibyte character set and useof MFC--> use standard windows libraries, it is working fine, but in failure case if am doing the above changes still it is not working. Getting 35 errors.

```
Errors: 1> Error 181    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\Devpt_branch\20433-21701-KM GUI Extraction\KalculationShadows\Debug\AggregatDTTrommel.obj'  
D:\Devpt_branch\20433-21701-KM GUI Extraction\ExeStub\LINK  ExeStub.`
```

Can anyone please help why it is not compiling if i changed to mulit-byte character set and why it is working with the old branch.?

```
HINSTANCE initH2oLibFilename(LPCSTR strFile, std::ostream& os)
{    
    HINSTANCE lib = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)strFile);
    if(!lib)
    {
        os << "Error loading \'" << strFile <<'\''<< std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}


HINSTANCE initH2oLibIF97(LPCSTR strPath, std::ostream& os)
{    
    std::string strFile(strPath);
    strFile += "H2O32Bit.dll";
    return initH2oLibFilename(strFile.c_str(), os);
}
```

I should not use casting. Because without casting in other branch it is working.

Comment: That's a linker error. You don't even have a program to run based on the source code you have. You are probably running an old executable (that is failing to load the DLL).

Comment: No its new executable, is there any configuration related changes do i need to do?

Comment: The error you've put in the question is the linker being unable to open the object file `AggregatDTTrommel.obj`. I'd be extremely surprised if your build system would continue to produce an executable after that error. Do a clean (rebuild all) build. Do you still get the linker error? Do you have an executable file?